# Equal strings doesn't return to true

Tags: python, dictionary, hash

I have started learning Python and I have started with the book Violent Python. In it the first chapter describes a script to crack *nix based password hashes with the help of `crypt` class. Here is the code:

```
import crypt
def testPass(cryptPass):
    salt = cryptPass[0:2]
    dictFile = open('dictionary.txt','r')
    for word in dictFile.readlines():
        word = word.strip('\n')
        cryptWord = crypt.crypt(word,salt)
        print cryptPass+":"cryptWord
        if(cryptPass == cryptWord):
            print "[+] Password found : "+word
            return

print "[-] Password Not Found.\n"
return
def main():
    passFile = open('passwords.txt')
    for line in passFile.readlines():
        if ":" in line:
            user = line.split(':')[0]
            cryptPass = line.split(':')[1].strip(' ')
            print "[*] Cracking Password For: "+user
            testPass(cryptPass)
if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

I have a passwords.txt file which contains the username:password(password hash) strings, and another file named dictionary.txt which contains the dictionary words.These are the contents of passwords.txt file :

```
apple:HXJintBqUVCEY
mango:HXInAjNhZF7YA
banana:HXKfazJbFHORc
grapes:HXtZSWbomS0xQ
```

and the dictionary.txt :

```
apple
abcd
efgh
ijkl
mnop
```

The password hash computed from testpass() method and the password hash from passwords.txt for username apple are equal , when I print both of them. But the output here for all 4 usernames is "[-] Password not found". Why the == test fails here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you have a trailing `\n` at the end of the line. Try change:

```
        cryptPass = line.split(':')[1].strip(' ')
```

to:

```
        cryptPass = line.split(':')[1].strip('\n').strip(' ')
```

or even simpler (as suggested in comments):

```
        cryptPass = line.split(':')[1].strip()
```

Comment: Using `.strip('\n ')` would be simpler than chaining two `strip` method calls.

Comment: `.strip()` will do for both newline and spaces

Comment: Thanks a lot. that did the trick, coming from java background never thought there'd a trailing \n at the end.

Comment: You're welcome. @MosesKoledoye You're right, I added that. I leave the original too because it explains how the problem solved better.